# Error: The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/***/'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, serviceconnection

Recently changed azure subscription and I need to add the same in Azure DevOps – service connection. When trying to create new service connection for the changed subscription I am getting below error -

Failed to query service connection API: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{id}/resourcegroups?api-

> version=2016-02-01'. Status Code: 'Unauthorized', Response from
>   server:
>   '{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant","message":"The
>   access token is from the wrong issuer
>   'https://sts.windows.net/{id}/'. It must match the tenant
>   'https://sts.windows.net/{id}/' associated with this
>   subscription. Please use the authority (URL)
>   'https://login.windows.net/{id}' to get the token. Note, if the
>   subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to
>   the services, but information about new tenant could take time to
>   propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription
>   and see this error message, please try back later."}}'

With the subscription - azure active directory is also changed. Do I need to change AD in AzureDevops? or How do I resolve this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your subscription is in another tenant, you may need to change it.

See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops