# Deploying azure static web app using VS code issue

Tags: azure

While deploying Node.js angular app to  Azure Static Web Apps from VS code, getting this issue in the terminal window.

[image]

This seems to happen I had change the azure subscription to trail account with login in VS  and try to deploy with swa command. Any suggestions how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Make sure you have logged into the same account in VSCode which you have azure subscription.

Comment: Instead of image share the error as a text message.

Answer (score 0):

> This seems to happen I had change the azure subscription to trail
> account with login in VS

If you have changed the Subscription in `VSCode` , make sure you have logged in and deploying the App service to the same Azure Account in Portal.

Check whether your Login Azure Account subscription is active or not.

> Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/{tenantid}' to get the token.

The error says to use the correct authority URL.

Check whether the correct Tenant id is passed in the authority URL or not.

Make sure the tenant id which is in the error is available in the subscription.

As mentioned in the [MDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token-examples), use the below command to get the authority URL.

```cs
az account get-access-token
```

[image]

[image]

Refer the similar issue addressed in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850839/error-the-access-token-is-from-the-wrong-issuer-https-sts-windows-net).